# Как сделать размер шрифта относительно его размера в pillow? PIL, Python

Tags: python, pil

Как сделать размер шрифта относительно его размера в pillow? PIL, Python
Я делаю программу, которая будет накладывать текст на изображение, но когда текст слишком большой, он
выходит за границы фото.

Comment: [ImageFont.getsize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/ImageFont.html#methods) возвращает размеры в пикселях, дальше можно подобрать методом научного тыка

Comment: Cпасибо, огромное